# How to make the length and width between "Graphics" moderate

Tags: html, css

I want to make the figure's length and width have proper distance.
But it has not been smooth.

I need the same distance for "tr" and "th".
Like this effect:

[image]

Distance between graphics is always different.

How can i do?

Below is my code，The distance of the width between items is wrong.

Thanks

```css
fieldset.scheduler-border {
  border: solid 3px #000000 !important;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

legend.scheduler-border {
  width: auto !important;
  border: none;
  font-size: 36px;
}

tr {
  display: block;
  margin: 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
    <legend class="scheduler-border"> Test </legend>
    <table id="ConnectionMonitorTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="50%">
            <svg width="150" height="100">
                            <rect width="150" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"></rect> />
                            <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">TEXT</text>
                        </svg>
          </th>
          <th width="50%">
            <svg width="150" height="100">
                            <rect width="150" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
                            <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">TEXT</text>
                        </svg>
          </th>

          <th width="50%">
            <svg width="150" height="100">
                            <rect width="150" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
                            <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">TEXT</text>
                        </svg>
          </th>
          <th width="50%">
            <svg width="150" height="100">
                            <rect width="150" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
                            <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">TEXT</text>
                        </svg>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th width="50%">
            <svg width="150" height="100">
                            <rect  width="150" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
                            <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">TEXT</text>
                        </svg>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Thank you so much

Comment: I cannot understand what you want this to look like. Can you share an image that shows what you're trying to create?

Comment: The spacing between the graphics is the same

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/aKWtgJX

Comment: I don't think a table is the right approach for this. Does it need to be a table or can the HTML change?

Comment: The table is used for future maintenance, such as the number of pages (data-page-number)

Comment: I know, its not helpful if it has to be a table for some reason, but this might actually be a good usecase for CSS grid. Way less code, easier to maintain and grid-gap does exactly what you are looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this using CSS Grid. Besides surrounding each block with a `div` wrapper, I created some basic grid rules. The type of grid uses [auto placement](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example17/). Using `grid-gap`, grid children will have at least `30px` of spacing between them. If the page is very wide, the gap will increase naturally. Hopefully you can start to see the power of CSS Grid for handling layouts like this.

```
.item-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 30px;
  …
}
```

## Demo

```css
fieldset.scheduler-border {
  border: solid 3px #000000 !important;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

legend.scheduler-border {
  width: auto !important;
  border: none;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.item-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 30px;
  padding: 0 30px 15px;
}

.item-container .item:not(:first-child) {}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
    <legend class="scheduler-border"> Test </legend>

    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">
        <svg width="150" height="100">
          <rect width="150" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
          <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">TEXT</text>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <svg width="150" height="100">
          <rect width="150" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
          <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">TEXT</text>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <svg width="150" height="100">
          <rect width="150" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
          <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">TEXT</text>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <svg width="150" height="100">
          <rect width="150" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
          <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">TEXT</text>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <svg width="150" height="100">
          <rect width="150" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
          <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">TEXT</text>
        </svg>
      </div>

    </div>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmfhqcok/3/)

Comment: This is exactly what i need

Comment: @JunJiaHuang I'm here to help.